# React router v4 ignores exact

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I'm trying to render NotFound component or redirect to root route using React router v4 when path is incorrect, but when I'm on "/" my app renders 2 components.

```
<Switch>
     <Navbar>
         <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
         <Route path="/Other" component={Other} />
         <Route component={NotFound} />
     </Navbar>
</Switch>
```

and my Navbar looks like:

```
render()
{
    return(
        <div>
            {/*Any content here*/}
            {this.props.children}
        </div>
    );
}
```

If I replace `<Route component={NotFound} />` to `<Redirect to="/" />` it looks working, but I'm getting an error: `Warning: You tried to redirect to the same route you're currently on: "/"`

Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The placement of your `Switch` component is incorrect, it should wrap the components children where `Routes` are defined

```
<Navbar>
     <Switch>
         <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
         <Route path="/Other" component={Other} />
         <Route component={NotFound} />
     </Switch>
</Navbar>
```